# How to have Excel return multiple cells of data from one search

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have two sheets in Excel.

The first sheet is called ***'Car Search'***.

The second sheet is called ***'Raw Data'***. This sheet contains a ***'Car ID'*** column for each car variant (e.g. VW Golf TDI has the Car ID 2612. VW Golf TSI has the Car ID 2613).

I want to search for the Car ID in the ***'Car Search'*** sheet and would like it to return all the data about that specific car from the ***'Raw Data'*** sheet.

I have tried using VLOOKUP but I don't know how it would be able to return data from multiple cells and columns.

Please see screenshot of both sheets below.

[image: Car Search]

[image: Raw Data]

Any help will be much appreciated!

***EDIT:***

I have one more issue: I have tried to use the same formula in the Notes field but it only picks up the values from the first ***'Notes'*** Column in the ***'Raw Data'*** sheet.
The formula is `=INDEX('Raw Data'!A:Z,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(E2,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))`

[image: Car Search 2]
[image: Raw Data 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Index / Match to solve your problem. Here is some pseudo code to your problem that you can adapt:

`=INDEX(RawData;MATCH(Car_ID;FirstColumn_RawData;0);MATCH(DataField;FirstRow_RawData;0)`

The first match function is used to find the row where the data you want from `CarID` resides, and the second match is used to find the column in which the data field you want to return is located.

Alternatively as has been suggested in another answer, simply use VLOOKUP multiple times.

Comment: This is definitely more 'drag and fillable' than the VLOOKUP solution, as long as the value in column A on the Car Search tab exactly matched the column name on the Raw Data tab. Replace the DataField variable in that Pseudo code with the field in column A

Comment: So I have manipulated your psuedocode and this is the formula:



`=INDEX('Raw Data'!A:A 'Raw Data';MATCH(Car ID;'Raw Data';0);MATCH(Car ID;2'Raw Data';0)`

But I get an error stating: We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more infor on common formula problems.

Comment: The first part of your INDEX formula is incorrect... you've put `'Raw Data'!A:A` when it should be `'Raw Data'!A:M` which looks at the whole of the Raw Data table. Similarly, you haven't put the column names in each of the MATCH formulas. Try `=INDEX('Raw Data'!A:M,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(A4,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))`

Comment: @Gallus - thanks. I have entered the formula into Cell B3 of 'Car Search' but it returns 0 as the result. Also I get another message stating: `'Careful, we found one or more circular references in your workbook that might cause your formulas to calculate incorrectly. FYI: A circular reference can be a formula that refers to its own cell value, or refers to a cell dependent on its own cell value.'`

Comment: That would be the formula for B4... in B3 you would put the Car ID you're trying to look up...

Comment: @howzat Do you have any calculations in the RawData?

Comment: @rohrl77 The circular reference comes from the fact the formula in B3 is trying to match the contents of B3 in the Raw Data... as such, it goes round in a loop... just needs moving...

Comment: @Gallus - Thank you, it's working! But, there is an issue with cells B15, C15 and D15. Using the same formula, it returns the results of Yes in all 3 cells. The value is correct, but it is appearing in all 3 cells, how can I make it blank for those cells?

Comment: That's a bit of a different question. You need to add an IF statement in there to say that IF the result of the INDEX formula is Yes, then do X (i.e. put an X in the box or whatever you want in there...). So: `=IF(INDEX(...)="Yes","X","")' in the 'Yes' column if you want to put an X in there, and then replace the '="Yes"' with '="No"' for the second column etc.

Comment: Right, I thought it may need that. So if I did this would it work?
`=IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!A:M,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(A15,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))="Yes","X","")`

Comment: Yes... and then you'd need to make the variants for the other two columns of 'No' and 'N/A'. p.s. please feel free to credit me when handing this work in ;-)

Comment: @rohrl77 - Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Gallus - Thank you also for adding to the answer!

Comment: @rohrl77 - I have another little issue, the formula isn't taking the Notes from the individual columns in the 'Raw Data' sheet. Is it because they are all named 'Notes'?

Comment: @howzat Yes it's because they are all named the same. What Excel will do is go to the first one it finds and ignore the rest. You need to make each column distinct. I.e. "Notes1", "Notes2", etc.

Answer (score 2):

VLOOKUP is what you are looking for, but you will need to repeat the formula for each of the columns you are dragging back.

The following would be the basic formula:

`=VLOOKUP($B$3,RawData,[Column No],FALSE)`

Where RawData is a named range for the second tab, You could replace it with:

`'Raw Data'!$A:$M`

[Column No] would be the variable between the cells you are dragging back and would relate to the positional column on the Raw Data sheet. Each of the fields on the Car Search sheet would need a corresponding formula for the [Column No] in it.

All you would then need to do is change the value in B3 to the car ID, and the other fields would update.

Comment: Probably important to note that the VLOOKUP formula doesn't 'drag and fill' like many others would, so you need to manually amend the [Column No] for each cell you copy it to. You only need to do this once though whilst setting up the template.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP will be solve your problem. learn and use VLOOKUP in multiple columns

Comment: A Bit more than a simple "Do it this way" is preferred on this site. If you don't want to give an exact answer, "Use VLOOKUP like this... and fit it for your answer" is better than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vlookup as many times as needed in a single cell:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,A3:E10,2)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,A3:E10,3)`

This will return the value matching A2 from range A3:E10 in column B, and then C, separated by a space